# Angular 4 animations on IE11 not working properly

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, angular-animations

```
Code sample
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/sT0YL2T3w940RPlIu1YL?p=preview

In this example you can see how the same animation applied ones to a table's tr is not animating and the same animation applied to a div is animating properly.

This only happens in IE11.

Do you have an explanation for this?

Answer (score -1):

Case angular-cli, write on polyfills.ts file:
import 'web-animations-js';

And install web-animations-js.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following to support `@angular/animation`. */

```
import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

Comment: Look at the posted example, the polyfill was added, same animation works on one component and it doesn't on another.

Comment: Hi when I uncomment import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.. Its throwing error. should I add it in dependencies ?